# Stop div scrolling when it reaches bottom of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to have a div stop scrolling on a page when it reaches the bottom edge of the browser window.  There's nothing below it and I'm trying to avoid empty space there.

I've seen many methods for stopping something at the top of the screen or when another div comes into view, but not this situation.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you add a quick jsfiddle?

Comment: lol yeah, add a fiddle. I'm lost because I thought that's how scrolling works...it stops at the bottom.

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue (padding/margin maybe), not so much a case for a  jQuery trick.

Comment: The layout is just a sidebar and content  area.  There isn't a header or footer.  On pages where the content is taller, i'd like the sidebar to stop scrolling once it reaches the edge of the screen, even as the content continues up.  Basically it needs to change to position fixed once the end of it's content is in view.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about having something stick to the bottom of a page once it has reached the bottom of the page so it doesn't continue working its way up the page?

If so, [Waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/) might be what you're looking for.

Just set a trigger for when the div has made it 0px above the bottom of the page and then have it change the div's "position" from whatever to "fixed" and "bottom" set to "0."